# How to insert the date in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to automate my life with batch files, and I am wondering if it is possible to plop in the date EX: `11/14/2020` in google forms using `send keys` .

Comment: Windows [tag:batch-file]s cannot interact with graphical user interfaces.  You will need to use a different scripting language like jscript, vbscript or powershell.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```vb
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep(1000)
WshShell.SendKeys Date
```

Comment: How would I use this with `SendKeys` in a batch file? Like this: `%SendKeys% = ("%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:0,2%")`?

Comment: @The_Plague Whoops wrong language :) I went ahead and fixed it for you. My bad.